# Why is the onclick attribute not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a function in PHP that is like JavaScript's alert() command, but the OK button's onclick attribute is not working!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    function alert($title, $text) {
        $html = '<div id="alert" style="background-color:lightGray; text-align:center; height:500px; width:500px; color: black; position:fixed; top: 50%; left:50%; margin-left:-250px; margin-top:-250px;">';
        $html = $html . '<h1 style="background-color:red; border-radius: 15px;">'. $title . '</h1>' . $text;
        $html = $html . '<br><br><button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:white; border:none;" onclick="document.getElementById(\"alert\").style.display=none">OK</button>';
        echo $html;
    }
    alert('Testing', 'Testing <em>testing</em><b>123</b>');
?>
```

What is wrong? I get an "alert box" but the OK button doesn't work!

Comment: if you're calilng this multiple times, you'll have multiple divs with the same id, and only the FIRST found id will ever get returned by `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: That's a quote mismatch in the ID selector !

Comment: @MarcB raises a valid point. If you have two alert boxes on the same page both of them will close one of them, which is strange. Generate a unique id every time you render an alert box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

element.style.display = 'none' instead of just none

ps just want to be clear of javascript concept

Comment: `'` will give a conflict with the existing string delimiter. You have to escape it at least once.

Comment: Thanks! New Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272026/how-do-i-get-the-parent-of-an-element

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

`document.getElementById(\"alert\").style.display=\"none\"`

I guess this also shows that your current approach is quite terrible. Having to add all those escapes without code highlighting is annoying.

See if you can find a way to do it properly ;) (hint: you can).