# How do I get the parent of an element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a function in PHP that is like JavaScript's alert() command, but when I click the OK button on one alert, all of the alerts disappear!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    function alert($title, $text) {
        $html = '<div id="alert" style="background-color:lightGray; text-align:center; height:500px; width:500px; color:black; position:fixed; top: 50%; left:50%; margin-left:-250px; margin-top:-250px;">';
        $html = $html . '<h1 style="background-color:red; border-radius: 15px;">'. $title . '</h1>' . $text;
        $html = $html . '<br><br><button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:white; border:none;" onclick="document.getElementById(\"alert\").style.display=none">OK</button>';
        echo $html;
    }
    alert('Testing', 'Testing <em>testing</em><b>123</b>');
    alert('Testg', 'Tesng <em>tting</em><b>23</b>');
    alert('Tsting', 'ing <em>tng</em><b>123</b>');
    alert('Testg', 'Teng <em>tesng</em><b>123</b>');
    alert('Teing', 'Teing <em>teng</em><b>123</b>');
?>
```

I tried using `this`, but that only made the button disappear! I need to find the parent element. How do I do that?

Comment: IDs have to be unique, so you can't have multiple DIVs with `id="alert"`.

Comment: You actually can, but if you try to do something with one, all of them get affected.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. I think jQuery assumes an ID selector will only return one element, and stops when it finds it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain javascript with [parentNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317):

```
element.parentNode
```

In jQuery:

```
element.parent()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.parentNode` to get the parent.